# Reorder factor in polycharts heatmap rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

Is there anyway to reorder factors in a polycharts heatmap in rCharts?

I have tried reorder it in data frame, but no luck.

```
library(rCharts)

dat <- data.frame(day1=rep(c("day 1", "day 2" ,"day 10"),3),
                 day2=rep(c("Mon","Sun","wed"),3),
                 value=1:9) 
dat$day1 <- factor(dat$day1, levels = c('day 1', 'day 2', 'day 10'))

plot <- rPlot(day1 ~ day2, color = 'value', data = dat ,type = 'tile', height = 600) 

plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the sort order with `guides`:

```
library(rCharts)

dat <- data.frame(day1=rep(c("day 1", "day 2" ,"day 10"),3),
                  day2=rep(c("Mon","Sun","wed"),3),
                  value=1:9) 

plot <- rPlot(day1~day2, color = 'value', data = dat, type = 'tile') 

# reverse the levels if you want the axis ordered in reverse

plot$guides(x = list(levels = c('Sun', 'Mon', 'wed')),
            y = list(levels = c('day 1', 'day 2', 'day 10')))

# i think you need to specify width & height this way

plot$addParams(width = 400, height = 400)

plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try appending a zero before all single digit entries under `dat$day1`. Its not the neatest solution but [after trying this out and not succeeding](http://www.r-bloggers.com/reordering-factor-levels-in-r-plots/), it would seem that `rPlot` prioritizes alphabetical ordering over factor levels. Looking forward to a neater solution from someone :-)

```
dat<-data.frame(day1=rep(c("day 01", "day 02" ,"day 10"),3),
                day2=rep(c("Mon","Sun","wed"),3), value=1:9)`

dat$day1 <- factor(dat$day1, levels = c('day 01', 'day 02', 'day 10'), ordered=T)

plot <- rPlot(day1 ~ day2, color = 'value', data = dat ,type ='tile', height=600)
plot
```

Comment: That was my original "inner hack" thought, too, but it occurred to me the OP would probably want the X-axis ordered, too.

Comment: Right, I see that now.